# Create a loop of Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a website where i can upload some images, i must do a different request for each image and while the photo is uploading show a loading icon, when the image is uploaded show the preview.
To do that I'm doing a promise loop, I know that i can use the .all function and handle the asynchronous request together but in this case the result will be that in the front end the images load together and all previews appears at the same time, I don't want this, I want show the loading icon for the real upload time for each image.
I don't know if I have well explained my problem

Comment: Please, don't try to describe the code. Post it instead. Questions should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You could use `reduce` with a default value of `Promise.resolve()` and set each promise up after the other.

**Example**

```js
function uploadImage() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

const images = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"];

const upload = images.reduce((prom, image) => {
  return prom
    .then(() => uploadImage(image))
    .then(() => console.log(`${image} uploaded!`));
}, Promise.resolve());

upload.then(() => console.log("All finished!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` function and there use `await` statement, but don't forget put `async` word to function